# the algebraic theory of obstruction of a homology theory

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, homological-algebra

In general homology group of a complex is  $Ker d/ Im d$(regardless of grading). However, in many case the square $d\circ d$ is not zero.  For example, the study of Floer thoery needs A infinity structure, this structure is due to the  geometric property.

Is there any general algebraic theory of the obsturction for the square of differential to be zero?

Comment: For most sources, a complex would have $d\circ d = 0$ so your terminology does seem a bit odd. What exactly is the definition of complex that you are using?  Perhaps you need to work with deformation theoretic ideas. The A-infinity structure you mentioned is in a related area.

Comment: The obstruction is the submodule $\operatorname{Im} (d\circ d)$. Without more context it seems difficult to say more.

Comment: Funnily enough, even in the context of $A_\infty$-structures one has $d\circ d = 0$ (although $d$ is no differential, but a co-differential). Are you interested in some examples of obstructions, as well?